# Jquery dialog show close button after certain time

Tags: jquery

How i can show a close button after certain elapsed, i tried settimeout but it wont work. can someone provide a basic sample to show the close button after certain time.

thanks

**EDIT:**
This is how i did custom buttons because someone asked me about this

```
 var myButtons = {
                'Close': function () {
             },
             'Do not show this again': function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: pagename,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            if (response.d == true) {
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
             };

$("#div").html("").dialog({ modal: true, resizable: false, width: 830, height: 580, show: 'slow', title: '', open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar", $("#div").parent()).hide(); }, buttons: myButtons });
```

thats how i did the custom buttons. the reason i had the mybuttons variable is because i use conditional statement and based on that i show different buttons when the dialog opens.

Comment: also the dialog will display initially but i want only the buttons to show after 10 secs or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/BU2TM/1/)

```
var $dialog = $('Your Dialog Div'); // Your Dialog Div

//Get Dialogs Parent and find the close button. 
//jQuery assigns .ui-dialog-titlebar-close class to the close X (a tag)
var $dialogCloseBtn = $dialog.parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close'); 

//hide the close button
$dialogCloseBtn.hide();

//show the close button after 10 seconds
setTimeout(function () {
    $dialogCloseBtn.fadeIn(100);
}, 10000);
```

**Assumption:** Above code is assuming that you want to hide/show the jQuery default Close button that you see it in the dialog's title.

Comment: well i want the custom buttons to work this way, but this code works.

Comment: @user1284460 can you post how you create those custom buttons.. you can add class to those buttons when initializing the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

if the dialog has a close button with `id=close_dialog_button`, give it a `display:none` style and then use this code:

```
$( "#dialog_div" ).dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#close_dialog_button").show();
    }, 10000);
 }
});
```